# standalone mysql 5.7 instance on a preemptible node, which settings can make it run in the most fault tolerant way possible?

Tags: mysql, fault-tolerance

Simplifying, I have a **standalone mysql instance** running on a docker container hosted on a **preemptible node**.
That means that at least ever 24 hours, the underlying node is killed, and a clean shutdown is never guaranteed.

Before going this route, I tested the setup by simulating this scenario on different loads, also write operations, and killing the underlying nodes by triggering a kernel panic: no issues even after thousands of restarts.

On the real world, from time to time - let's say once a month over 3000 mysql instances - a DB gets corrupted, and it needs recovery (force recovery, full dump, reload of the dump).

What is the best set of options I could configure to make sure mysql operates in a way where, even with frequent kills of the server, it will not write inconsistent data? Sacrificing performance is not an issue.

The disk is a google cloud compute engine "standard persistent disk".
This is the config it currently has (mysql is running on docker, so it requires *aio = OFF*):

```
max_connections = 60
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
tmp_table_size = 4M
key_buffer_size = 8M
query_cache_size = 4M
query_cache_limit = 512K
thread_stack = 128K
performance_schema = 0
show_compatibility_56 = 1
innodb-use-native-aio = OFF
```

**I am looking for my.cfg settings to make mysql as crash-proof as possible, not architectural solutions**

*Edit 25/03/21* I am currently testing the following:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
```

The first two are defaults, added just to be sure. It looks like O_DIRECT is the only step closer to the goal.
Interesting doc on mysql writing to google cloud disks and data sync techniques: https://dotmanila.com/2017/09/o_dsync-flush-method-for-mysql-on-google-cloud/

Comment: Try looking at the following https://youtu.be/0CqMv0ucqFA?t=2269 it talks about crash recovery for Mysql.

Comment: @FanofSam the question is not about crash recovery.

Answer (score -1):

3 servers for each of your 3K instances.  Optionally each of these 9K MySQL instances would be in VMs or docker or whatever.

But...  The 3 instances for each dataset *must* be in 3 geographical locations.  And be in a Galera cluster of those 3 nodes.  (InnoDB clustering is another option.)

Any instance can be killed abruptly.  It could either be revived or you could even put an 'empty' machine in its place.  Galera will recover -- either by incrementally updating (IST) the revived instance or by starting from scratch (SST).

Even the entire datacenter going down should be fully recoverable.  That datacenter might have 1 node of each of your 3K clusters, but it *must not* have two nodes of any cluster.

That handles any "single point of failure" -- a disk, a server, even a datacenter.

One could even argue that this obviates the need for RAID-1/5/6/10 on the disks.

I haven't thought through all the details, but I think 5 Galera nodes spread across 5 datacenters will be fully safe against any 2 points of failure.

Don't forget to worry about network failures.  For example, do the datacenters have *two* cables connecting to the Internet (or private cable)?  And software failres.

Comment: The point here is consistency of the binlog and data... since every 24 hours the node is killed.

Comment: @Michele - Clients need to check for errors after every SQL statement and gracefully handle the error that could occur when the server dies.

Comment: that's not relevant either, as you can see in the original answer.